# CherryPy is not respecting desired logging format

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

I am trying to configure CherryPy's logging format.  CherryPy uses the logging module in python so this has been easy to do however it appears that CherryPy still inserts it's own timestamp into the actual "message" of the log.  **How can I get CherryPy to not insert it's own timestamp into the "message"**?

Below is a small incomplete example of the code that demonstrates what i'm trying to do and the undesired output.

```
main.py
...
cherrypy_logger = logging.getlogger('cherrypy.error')
cherrypy_logger.handlers = [] # remove any previous handlers the logger had
new_handler = logging.streamHandler()
new_formatter = logging.formatter('blah blah blah ....: %(message)s')
new_handler.setformatter(new_formatter)
cherrypy_logger.addhandler(new_handler)
....
```

Then when the CherryPy lib/module logs something I get the following:

"blah blah blah ...: **[Jan/17/07 23:59:59 ]** Engine Started ..... "

I could be doing something wrong, but it **seems** like CheeryPy is inserting a timestamp in the string it's submitting to the logger with no regard to how the developer may want to show the time in the logs. How can I fix this?

**NOTE: the above code is from memory and is the bare minimum to get my point across (hopefully).  It will not compile/run.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do some little changes in CherryPy Log without changing source code is using method or property hacking, for example:

To modify the datetime fomatter you can change time() method.

```
cherrypy._cplogging.LogManager.time = lambda self : \
     datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")[:23]
```

To modify the string formatter of access_log you can use:

```
    cherrypy._cplogging.LogManager.access_log_format = (
       '{t} MYLOG {h} "{r}" {s} {b} "{f}" "{a}"'
       if six.PY3 else
       '%(t)s MYLOG %(h)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
    )
```

And finally you can modify string formatter of error_log using:

```
    new_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s MYLOG %(message)s")

    for h in cherrypy.log.error_log.handlers:
        h.setFormatter(new_formatter)
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Better late than never....  thanks for the help.  For future record, the trick worked well enough with a little shoehorning.

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question:

It turns out that CherryPy was in fact inserting a timestamp into the "message"

The following code can be found in _cplogging.py

`self.error_log.log(severity, ' '.join((self.time(), context, msg)), exc_info=exc_info)`

This, IMHO, is a poor way to insert a timestamp into the log because of the inflexability to change the logging format.  For now I've changed the line to read like this:

`self.error_log.log(severity, ' '.join((context, msg)), exc_info=exc_info)`

which fixes the problem for me however other bits of code will need a few more tweaks to make it a proper patch, which I'll see if I can do and submit.

PS. The CherryPy access log suffers from a very similar issue.

Anyways, hope this helps out somebody else!

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble finding a description of the access_log_format template vars, so I've retrieved them from the cherrypy source (site-packages/cherrypy/_cplogging.py) of 18.6.0 for convenience.

Default format:

```
access_log_format = '{h} {l} {u} {t} "{r}" {s} {b} "{f}" "{a}"'
```

Template var defaults:

```
atoms = {'h': remote.name or remote.ip,
         'l': '-',
         'u': getattr(request, 'login', None) or '-',
         't': self.time(),
         'r': request.request_line,
         's': status,
         'b': dict.get(outheaders, 'Content-Length', '') or '-',
         'f': dict.get(inheaders, 'Referer', ''),
         'a': dict.get(inheaders, 'User-Agent', ''),
         'o': dict.get(inheaders, 'Host', '-'),
         'i': request.unique_id,
         'z': LazyRfc3339UtcTime(),
        }
```

For example, here is the function I call to configure CherryPy logging for my project. This function is called before cherrypy.engine.start() and cherrypy.engine.block()

```
def configure_logger():
   pst = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
   cherrypy._cplogging.LogManager.time = lambda self: datetime.now().astimezone(pst).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")

   #Default access_log_format '{h} {l} {u} {t} "{r}" {s} {b} "{f}" "{a}"'
   #h - remote.ip, l - "-", u - login (or "-"), t - time, r - request line, s - status, b - content length
   #f - referer, a - User Agent, o - Host or -, i - request.unique_id, z - UtcTime
   cherrypy._cplogging.LogManager.access_log_format = '{t} ACCESS {s} {r} {h} {b} bytes'
```